# iTunes 10.6.3 opens every time I put in an audio CD

Tags: itunes

In system preferences> CDs & DVDs I have everything set to ignore. Yet iTunes still opens every time I put in an audio CD - is there a way to turn this off?

As a follow up in iTunes > Preferences > General > When You Insert A CD: I have the following options

- Show CD (The selected option)
- Begin Playing
- Ask To Import CD
- Import CD
- Import CD and Eject

There is no ignore option within iTunes - is there some other way to disable iTunes opening?

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes you can go to preferences > General > you can choose among:

– display 
– play 
– import 
– import and eject

just choose display. It seems that you can't get rid of this trouble.

Comment: What version of iTunes are you using I have the following options (Show CD, Begin Playing, Ask To Import CD, Import CD, and Import CD and Eject)

Comment: OK... they are the same but with different name